How do I fix error: Test-NetConnection : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'if'
I am trying to mount a File share using the Active Directory or Microsoft Entra auth method. I have the method enabled, I have the PC that I am trying to mount the file share to is enrolled to Intune and the user logged in under their Microsoft Entra ID, and am using the PowerShell script generated by the "Connect" window. Here is the script I am using (with the file share info redacted):
$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <<file_share_name>>.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
 # Mount the drive
 New-PSDrive -Name M -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\<<file_share_name>>.file.core.windows.net\u-brandonp" -Persist
} else {
 Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}

However, when I try to run it, I am getting this error message:
Screenshot of Error
Any help on how to resolve this would be great!
Thanks!
I tried the provided PowerShell script and am getting an error.

Hi @Mike, Welcome to SO. May I know the latest status of the issue and have you got a chance to check my answer below with an issue-reproducing sample. Hope it helps resolve your issue in this post. Thx.

Hi @Mike, If by any chance the findings below can help resolve your issue in this post, please feel welcome to let us know. Thx and happy weekends.

I could reproduce the issue when the if expression was in the same line of the command Test-NetConnection, which would make PowerShell consider they were parts of one single command. Please make sure if expression is written in another line of your script.


Hi, I just tried using that code and it is giving me this error now - Screenshot

The same script in your original post works in my PowerShell prompt. Please compare the issue-reproducing image in my answer, which was wrong. Please make sure the if expression is not in the same line with Test-NetConnection command. In case the issue still persists, would you please share an update in your original post with a screenshot showing the commands running in your PowerShell except for the error message only, so that we can help compare the differences in syntax?

Please don't forget to scrub the sensitive information like account name, password, etc. in the screenshot, as the community is publicly visible.
